# g++ with Dev-C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, dev-c++

It has come to my understanding that the error

```
[Linker error] undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
```

is caused by trying to compile a C++ program with the gcc compiler. This would be solved by compiling the program with a g++ compiler, but how does one get Dev-C++ to use the g++ compiler???

Comment: shows us your compile command line

Comment: `gcc` is for C code, `g++` is for C++ code. I don't have Dev-C++ installed, so, I could be wrong, but try to find something like _Tools -> Compiler options_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure your project is a C++ project, not a C project. Last time I was forced to use Dev-C++, I was unable to find a working method of doing this. You may have to delete the project file and create a new one.
2. Get rid of that broken piece of junk. There are far better IDEs available. Here are two:

   - [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/)
   - [Qt Creator](http://qt-project.org/downloads#qt-creator)

Answer (score 0):

That error may also be caused by the absence of libstdc++, make sure that you're linking to that library via '-lstdc++', this should be the last linking command.